# How can I override an admin e-mail template using my design folder?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, adminhtml, email-templates, design

I'm trying to override `module-user/view/adminhtml/email/user_notification.html` in my Magento 2 installation. I know how I can do this in the admin by creating a new template that gets stored in the database, but I want the file to be in my `app/design`-folder. So how can I do this?

I already tried copying the file to the following locations, but none seem to work:

- `app/design/adminhtml/Magento/Magento_User/email/user_notification.html`
- `app/design/adminhtml/Magento/default/Magento_User/email/user_notification.html`
- `app/design/adminhtml/Magento/backend/Magento_User/email/user_notification.html`

Can anyone point me in the right direction?